# SQL get latest row in one to many relationship using where clause only

Tags: sql, db2

I have two tables in which (roll_no) is same in both tables.
I have a table (student) having columns name and roll_no. e.g

```
roll_no    name
----------------
123        John
```

It has relation with another table (student_changed). Which has columns name, roll_no and LastEditTime. e.g.

```
roll_no    name     LastEditTime
--------------------------------------
123        Johny    2017-11-09 06:00:00
123        John     2017-11-08 07:00:00
```

What I want to ask is, how can I get the join having the most recent **LastEditTime**. 
There are many similar questions but my limitation is that I can only use/modify **where** clause.
e.g. 
I cannot modify the select query as well. 
Consider it like this

```
select * from student, student_changed <-- *this part cannot be changed*
where <-- This can be modified
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the answers but I managed to get it working by the following where clause.

```
where student.roll_no = student_changed.roll_no 
and LASTEDITTIME in(select max(LASTEDITTIME) from student_changed where student.roll_no = student_changed.roll_no)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
select roll_no,name, max(LastEditTime) 
from table2
group by 
roll_no,name;
```

Update 1:

```
select table1.roll_no,table1.name, max(table2.LastEditTime) 
from table2 join table1 on table1.roll_no=table2.roll_no 
group by 
table1.roll_no,table1.name;
```

One table is enough for your requirement.

Update 2:

```
select table1.roll_no,table1.name, max(table2.LastEditTime) 
from table2 join table1 
where table1.roll_no=table2.roll_no 
group by table1.roll_no,table1.name;
```

Update 3:

```
select table1.roll_no,table1.name,table2.LastEditTime 
from table2 join table1 
where 
(table1.roll_no,table1.name,table2.lastEditTime) in (select table1.roll_no,table1.name, max(table2.LastEditTime) from table2 join table 1 on table1.roll_no=table2.roll_no
group by table1.roll_no,table1.name);
```

Comment: I am using a corporate software i.e. IBM Maximo where we do not have such freedom of creating / deleting tables without downtime. I am confined to creating a join between these two tables using a where clause only

Comment: This query doesn't create/delete any tables inside the db.

Comment: @AhmedRana If you wish to check `table1.roll_no` and `table2.roll_no`, you can use join other wise it doesn't need. now i have updated my answer. try with this query.

Comment: Thanks for the replies but the joins are created inside Maximo in which we only select the two tables and the where clause joining e.g. the multi join where clause would be.
table1.roll_no = table2.roll_no

Comment: @AhmedRana I can't get what are you trying. This query satisfies  your requirement. if you want to use `where` instead of `on` you can replace and use.

Comment: I cannot modify the select query as well. Consider it like this 
select * from table1 join table2 
where ..... I can only modify the where cluase

Comment: @AhmedRana NO prob then put `table1.roll_no=table2.roll_no` inside your `where` field.

Comment: but this will give me all rows. I need the row which was last modified i.e. have the highest lastedittime

Comment: @AhmedRana Can you get output from my new update 3 query ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159056/discussion-between-uchiha-itachi-and-ahmedrana).

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the join. Table `student_changed` has all you need:

```
select roll_no, name, max(LastEditTime) as LastEditTime
from student_changed
group by roll_no, name
```